# GROUP BY timestamp interval 10 minutes PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, grouping

I need to group by a period of time spliting up by 10 minutes.

I have this query below that returns me a result set:

```
SELECT timestamp
    FROM table_1, table_2_shape_polygon
    WHERE ST_Within(earthnetworks_geometry_raios, poligono_geometry)
      AND timestamp 
      BETWEEN '2013-04-07 15:30:00' AND '2013-04-07 16:50:00'
      AND type = 0
      AND id_polygon = 2
```

My result set is like this:

```
"2013-04-07 15:30:55"
"2013-04-07 15:32:52"
"2013-04-07 15:32:52"
"2013-04-07 15:34:21"
"2013-04-07 15:39:09"
"2013-04-07 16:24:25"
"2013-04-07 16:29:58"
"2013-04-07 16:33:22"
"2013-04-07 16:34:30"
"2013-04-07 16:35:09"
"2013-04-07 16:36:54"
"2013-04-07 16:38:40"
"2013-04-07 16:39:37"
"2013-04-07 16:39:37"
"2013-04-07 16:39:38"
"2013-04-07 16:39:38"
"2013-04-07 16:39:44"
"2013-04-07 16:39:56"
"2013-04-07 16:40:03"
"2013-04-07 16:40:04"
"2013-04-07 16:41:22"
"2013-04-07 16:41:27"
"2013-04-07 16:41:38"
"2013-04-07 16:41:38"
"2013-04-07 16:42:24"
"2013-04-07 16:42:39"
"2013-04-07 16:45:00"
"2013-04-07 16:45:40"
"2013-04-07 16:49:43"
```

I have all timestamps in between a period, but I need to group it every 10 minutes and I have no idea how. I tried `date_trunc` which does not have the precision I need.

ex: between `2013-04-07 15:30:00, 2013-04-07 15:40:00 5 results`.

How can I do this?

---

I tried this and it did not work as expected.

```
SELECT
    timestamp 'epoch' +
    INTERVAL '1 second' * round((extract('epoch' from earthnetworks_dt_horario) / 600) * 600) as horario,
    count(earthnetworks_dt_horario)
FROM raios.earthnetworks, raios.earthnetworks_teste_poligono
WHERE ST_Within(earthnetworks_geometry_raios, poligono_geometry)
      AND earthnetworks_dt_horario 
      BETWEEN '2013-04-07 15:30:00' AND '2013-04-07 16:50:00'
      AND earthnetworks_num_tipo = 0
      AND id_poligono = 2
GROUP BY 
round(extract('epoch' from earthnetworks_dt_horario) / 600), earthnetworks_dt_horario
```

This is the result set not grouped:

> ```
> "2013-04-07 16:29:58";1
> "2013-04-07 16:34:30";1
> "2013-04-07 16:33:22";1
> "2013-04-07 16:39:44";1
> "2013-04-07 16:39:56";1
> "2013-04-07 16:42:24";1
> "2013-04-07 16:41:38";2
> "2013-04-07 16:24:25";1
> "2013-04-07 16:39:38";2
> "2013-04-07 16:42:39";1
> "2013-04-07 16:41:27";1
> "2013-04-07 16:36:54";1
> "2013-04-07 16:45:00";1
> "2013-04-07 16:40:04";1
> "2013-04-07 16:40:03";1
> "2013-04-07 15:34:21";1
> "2013-04-07 15:30:55";1
> "2013-04-07 15:39:09";1
> "2013-04-07 16:49:43";1
> "2013-04-07 16:45:40";1
> "2013-04-07 16:35:09";1
> "2013-04-07 16:38:40";1
> "2013-04-07 16:39:37";2
> "2013-04-07 16:41:22";1
> "2013-04-07 15:32:52";2
> ```

It did not work.

Comment: You could convert the timestamp into a varchar and substring it to something like "2013-04-07 15:3" then group by that field. Might be a taxing method compared to the mentioned timestamp functions in the other answers.

Answer (score 26):

You can use this for PostgreSQL.  600 is 10 minutes in seconds. The idea is to convert timestamp to epoch, divide by interval desired in minutes then round to get the desired interval

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, 
to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from timestamp_column) / 600 )) * 600) 
AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as interval_alias
FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY interval_alias
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few handy [datetime functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). First, deconstruct the timestamps with `date_trunc` to each hour, then do some integer division with the minutes with `date_part` to make an interval, which is recombined.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
    date_trunc('hour', timestamp) +
    (((date_part('minute', ts)::integer / 10::integer) * 10::integer)
     || ' minutes')::interval AS ten_min_timestamp
FROM sometable_or_joins_or_whatever
GROUP BY ten_min_timestamp;
```

Comment: This works well with all the conditions, must have been upvoted. But I am not sure  why `|| ' minutes'` has been used in `date_part`.

Comment: `integer || 'minutes'` is used to create an interval type, for example "8 minutes", which is added to the timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345308/749063) by replacing 300 by 600 (the number of seconds in 10 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar in mySql by grouping by timestamp - `MOD(timestamp, 600)`, the return value of which will be same for all timestamps within a 10 min (600 sec) intevall.